# Updating a stateful widget variable after it has rendered?

Tags: flutter, bloc, statefulwidget

I'm using a [TabBarView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBarView-class.html) with two tabs that each display a Stateful widget-- Let's call them the Main Widget and the Configuration Widget.

The Configuration Widget serves as a 'configuration section' for the Main Widget-- I use it to set things like the background color and a URL variable in the Main Widget that's used to grab data from a web service.

The Main Widget has a ListView that is populated by that web service. I'm using the [Bloc](https://github.com/felangel/bloc) pattern to send events from one widget to the other, which is how the Configuration Widget sends a URL value over to the Main Widget-- an event is fired, which courtesy of the bloc becomes a 'state' object with the new URL in it that the Main Widget can read in its constructor and use to build the ListView.

Right now I use the [wantKeepAlive](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin/wantKeepAlive.html) mechanism in the Main Widget to avoid repopulating the ListView if I haven't changed the URL in the Configuration Widget-- if I don't do so the Main Widget rebuilds whenever I return to its tab, even if I haven't changed anything in the Configuration Widget.

What I want to do is have that value set selectively, so that when the URL is changed in the configuration, update the `wantKeepAlive` value to `false` so the ListView *does* rebuild with the new URL.  But when it's done building, set the `wantKeepAlive` value back to `true`, so no rebuilding is done, until the next URL change.

Is there a lifecycle method I can call when a `build()` method is completed, where I can set the `wantKeepAlive` setting?  I don't think doing so in the build method itself would work.  Open to suggestions, and thanks.

Comment: `"Right now I use the wantKeepAlive mechanism in the Main Widget to avoid repopulating the ListView "` -   you mean your bloc performs some heavy jobs when switching between your two tabs?

Comment: @pskink nothing heavy, just sends out an event when warranted or makes a webservice call.  It's not making long calculations or anything along those lines.

Comment: so whats wrong in repopulating the ListView in that case? widget rebuilding is very cheap in flutter...

Comment: @pskink I guess I misunderstood what you meant by 'heavy'-- calling the webservice takes a few seconds, and I'd prefer not to have to wait for the list to redraw if I don't have to, if the data is already there.

Comment: OK the question is why would you want to call your web service each time you switch the tabs - normally only your ListView needs to be rebuilt using the data that is already fetched from the web service - it seems that your bloc pattern is not used correctly

Comment: That's the thing: I don't want to call the web service whenever I switch tabs, not unless I've changed the URL.  The problem for me was figuring out how to tell the Main Widget to change the `wantKeepAlive` property when the URL id changed, so its bloc could make the webservice call.

Comment: you dont need any `wantKeepAlive` nor trickss like `addPostFrameCallback` - just make sure your bloc does not reload remote data every time you rebuild your `ListView`

Comment: The TabBarView destroys and reloads widgets when you change tabs, so I need to use the `wantKeepAlive` variable to prevent that.  Otherwise my bloc (which is used in the stateful widget constructor) will call the webservice every time I change tabs back, no matter if I need to or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195482/discussion-between-larryq-and-pskink).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `addPostFrameCallback` of your `WidgetsBinding` instance to execute some code after your widget was built.

```
  _onLayoutDone(_) {
    //add your code here
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_onLayoutDone);
    super.initState();
  }
```